# PyQt5 designer size policy not reflecting properly in preview

Tags: python, css, pyqt5

I was prototyping a sidebar for my project in pyqt5 designer, and I noticed that it was rather hard to get the sidebar to resize properly. Ideally the buttons at the top of the sidebar should remain the same size and remain at the top no matter how you try to resize it, and the settings button at the bottom should remain at the bottom. However, what I got instead is that the buttons seem to have fixed positions and if I try to make it smaller the buttons simply go out of the screen, and if I make it larger the sidebar does not enlarge with the screen. Here's the code sample in .ui format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="enabled">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1585</width>
    <height>1072</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QWidget" name="Sidebar" native="true">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>61</width>
      <height>1071</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="sizePolicy">
     <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Expanding">
      <horstretch>0</horstretch>
      <verstretch>0</verstretch>
     </sizepolicy>
    </property>
    <property name="minimumSize">
     <size>
      <width>61</width>
      <height>1071</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="maximumSize">
     <size>
      <width>61</width>
      <height>16777215</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
     <enum>Qt::NoContextMenu</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="autoFillBackground">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QWidget {
background-color: rgb(234, 234, 234);}</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="TabBtn1">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>0</x>
       <y>0</y>
       <width>61</width>
       <height>61</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="mouseTracking">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background: rgb(234, 234, 234);
}

QPushButton:hover {
    background: rgb(195, 195, 195);
}</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string/>
     </property>
     <property name="icon">
      <iconset>
       <normaloff>../Downloads/machine-learning.png</normaloff>../Downloads/machine-learning.png</iconset>
     </property>
     <property name="iconSize">
      <size>
       <width>40</width>
       <height>40</height>
      </size>
     </property>
     <property name="checkable">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="TabBtn2">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>0</x>
       <y>60</y>
       <width>61</width>
       <height>61</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background: rgb(234, 234, 234);
}

QPushButton:hover {
    background: rgb(195, 195, 195);
}</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string/>
     </property>
     <property name="icon">
      <iconset>
       <normaloff>../Downloads/contact-list.png</normaloff>../Downloads/contact-list.png</iconset>
     </property>
     <property name="iconSize">
      <size>
       <width>40</width>
       <height>40</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="TabBtn4">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>0</x>
       <y>180</y>
       <width>61</width>
       <height>61</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background: rgb(234, 234, 234);
}

QPushButton:hover {
    background: rgb(195, 195, 195);
}</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string/>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="TabBtn5">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>0</x>
       <y>240</y>
       <width>61</width>
       <height>61</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background: rgb(234, 234, 234);
}

QPushButton:hover {
    background: rgb(195, 195, 195);
}</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string/>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="TabBtn5_2">
     <property name="enabled">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>0</x>
       <y>1010</y>
       <width>61</width>
       <height>61</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="sizePolicy">
      <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Fixed">
       <horstretch>0</horstretch>
       <verstretch>1</verstretch>
      </sizepolicy>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background: rgb(234, 234, 234);
}

QPushButton:hover {
    background: rgb(195, 195, 195);
}</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string/>
     </property>
     <property name="icon">
      <iconset>
       <normaloff>../Downloads/settings (1).png</normaloff>../Downloads/settings (1).png</iconset>
     </property>
     <property name="iconSize">
      <size>
       <width>40</width>
       <height>40</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="TabBtn3">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>0</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>61</width>
       <height>61</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background: rgb(234, 234, 234);
}

QPushButton:hover {
    background: rgb(195, 195, 195);
}</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string/>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QStackedWidget" name="stackedWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>60</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>1521</width>
      <height>1071</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="currentIndex">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="page"/>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="page_2"/>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I've tried playing around with the size policies of the buttons as well as the widget it is in, unfortunately I don't see anything that fixes it.

Comment: You need to use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) (see how to [use them in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html)), and note that size policies are only effective for layout purposes, if they are not part of a layout, setting them is useless.

Answer (score 0):

import os

class UI(QMainWindow):

** add this line to your code

```
os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"
```